# How to add two numbers on the right side of the list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make a list and adding or say merging numbers to the left of the list according to the length if they are similar then only, and in their places a zero is added. The code I have attached below. But when I try doing it for the right side, like merging should happen on the right side, it is not happening.

For ex:

```
[2,0,2,4] -> [4,4,0,0] ---- for left merge
[2,0,2,4] -> [0,0,4,4] ---- for right merge
```

```
def try_merge(ol):
    
    temp_list=[]
    final_list=[]
    
    for e in ol:
        if e !=0:
            temp_list.append(e)

    while len(temp_list) < len(ol):
        temp_list.append(0)
        
    count=0
    var=0
    
    if len(temp_list)%2==0:
        temp_list.append(0)
        
    while count <len(temp_list) - 1:
        if temp_list[count]==temp_list[count+1]:
            add = 2 *temp_list[count]
            final_list.append(add)
            count=count+2
        else:
            var=var+1
            final_list.append(temp_list[count])
            count=count+1
    
    if count< len(temp_list):
        final_list.append(temp_list[count])
       
    fcount=len(final_list)
    ocount=len(ol)
    
    while fcount<ocount:
        final_list.append(0)
        fcount=fcount+1
        
    if var==len(ol):
        temp_list.pop()
        return temp_list
    else:
        return final_list

a=[2,2,0,4]
b=try_merge(a)
print(b)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, but if you want to add an element to the beginning of a list, you can do `l.insert(0, new_element)`

Comment: what is the output for this `[2,0,3,4]`?

Comment: Do you know the game 2048?

Comment: I'm trying to resolve the logic of that 2048 game by using lists

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote basically accounts for adding elements to the end of a list, that is, it works for merging left. To merge right, you'll need to change things to the opposite. I'll try to keep the code as close to yours as possible:

```
def merge_right(ol):
    
    temp_list=[]
    final_list=[]
    
    for e in ol:
        if e !=0:
            temp_list.append(e)

    while len(temp_list) < len(ol):
        temp_list.insert(0,0)
        
    count=0
    var=0
    
    if len(temp_list)%2==0:
        temp_list.insert(0,0)
        
    N = len(temp_list) - 1
    while N-count > 0:
        v = N - count
        if temp_list[v]==temp_list[v-1]:
            add = 2 *temp_list[v]
            final_list.insert(0,add)
            count=count+2
        else:
            var=var+1
            final_list.insert(0,temp_list[v])
            count=count+1
    
    
    if count < len(temp_list):
        final_list.insert(0, temp_list[N-count])
    
    
    fcount=len(final_list)
    ocount=len(ol)
    
    while fcount<ocount:
        final_list.insert(0,0)
        fcount=fcount+1
        

    if var==len(ol):
        temp_list.pop(0)
        return temp_list
    else:
        return final_list


a=[2,2,0,4]
b=merge_right(a)
print(b)
# [0, 0, 4, 4]
```

Comment: thank you so much sir for the response and it was useful. But could you just tell me the logic behind the solution?@Mercury

Comment: The logic is exactly same as your own solution, but only list.append(value) has been changed to list.insert(0,value) to insert values to the start, rather than the end of the list. Also, temp_list is being accessed from right to left, by using N-count rather than just count. Previously, you looked at values two at a time from the left, slowly going towards the right; but with N-count, now you're looking from right to left.

Comment: Ohk sir understood. Thank you so much. If i get stuck anywhere will come back to you!

Comment: Can I use recursion to include more lists in order to display it like a game grid after merging. For example:  [4,4,0,0]                                                                                               
                                      [4,2,4,0]                                                                                                              
                                      [2,4,0,0][

Comment: Can someone relpy to it as soon as possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to simplify the logic for the left and right merge functions. It works like below: 1. Remove zeros from the list and iterate over it to check if we can merge adjacent cells if the value is the same.
2. The left_merge iterates the list from left to right while the right_merge iterates it from right to left.

```
def initializeListWithZeros(listLength):
    newList=[]
    for i in range(0,listLength):
        newList.append(0)
    return newList

def returnListRemoveZeros(listParam):
    newList=[i for i in listParam if i != 0]
    return newList


def left_merge(ol):
    merged=initializeListWithZeros(len(ol))
    trimzeros=returnListRemoveZeros(ol)

    print("Original",ol)
    print("Without zeros", trimzeros)
    listlen = len(trimzeros)
    i=0
    mergeIndex=0
    while i<listlen:
        if(i+1<listlen):
            if(trimzeros[i]==trimzeros[i+1]):
                merged[mergeIndex]=trimzeros[i]+trimzeros[i+1]
                i += 2
                mergeIndex+=1
            else:
                merged[mergeIndex]=trimzeros[i]
                i += 1
                mergeIndex += 1
        else:
            merged[mergeIndex] = trimzeros[i]
            i += 1
            mergeIndex += 1

    return merged


def right_merge(ol):
    merged=initializeListWithZeros(len(ol))
    trimzeros=returnListRemoveZeros(ol)

    print("Original",ol)
    print("Without zeros", trimzeros)
    listlen = len(trimzeros)
    i=listlen-1
    mergeIndex=len(ol)-1
    while i>=0:
        if(i-1>=0):
            if(trimzeros[i]==trimzeros[i-1]):
                merged[mergeIndex]=trimzeros[i]+trimzeros[i-1]
                i -= 2
                mergeIndex-=1
            else:
                merged[mergeIndex]=trimzeros[i]
                i -= 1
                mergeIndex -= 1
        else:
            merged[mergeIndex] = trimzeros[i]
            i -= 1
            mergeIndex -= 1

    return merged



a = [2, 2, 0, 2]
b = left_merge(a)
print("Left merged",b)
c= right_merge(a)
print("Right merged",c)
```